# Apply changes to all <img> by JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to force a `filter` into all `img` tags in page by pushing a button. Number of images varies in different pages. I came this far:

```
function ccbfunction(wt) {
    var w = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    var z;
    if (wt == 0) {
        z = "#e0e0e0";
    } else {
        z = "#fff";
    };
    w[0].style.filter = "brightness(80%)";
}
```

Now it's just working on first image and I don't know how to select all the `<img>`s. The number of images isn't constant so I don't use `for` loop.

Comment: Is using jQuery an option ?  your life would be so simpler then...

Comment: @Exception_al If I have no other choice.

Comment: @Exception_al Yes yours is working, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just try this

```
for(var i=0;i<w.length;i++){
  w[i].style.filter="brightness(80%)";
}
```

I guess this should help;

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to catch all the `img` elements into an `array-like` node list, using `document.getElementsByTagName("img")`.

Then transform it into an array, using `Array#from` and simply iterate over it using `Array#forEach` and apply new `style` to the each element.

```js
function ccbfunction(wt) {
  var w = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
  var z;

  if (wt == 0) {
    z = "#e0e0e0";
  } else {
    z = "#fff";
  };
  Array.from(w).forEach(v => v.style.filter = "brightness(40%)");
}

ccbfunction();
```

```html
<img src='http://placehold.it/150x150'>
<img src='http://placehold.it/250x150'>
<img src='http://placehold.it/250x150'>
<img src='http://placehold.it/200x150'>
<img src='http://placehold.it/150x200'>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate over the objects like :

```
var w= document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for (var i = 0; i < w.length; i++) {
    // Perform activity on list[i]
    w[i].style.filter="brightness(80%)";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a forEach loop:

```
w.forEach(function(image) {

 image.style.filter = "brightness(80%)";

});
```

It loops trough each instance, so it doesn't matter how many img tags there are on the page

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByTagName` returns a nodeList an array like object, however if you want to iterate over nodeList, you can use a workaround to use Array methods like forEach on nodeList.

Using `Array.prototype.forEach.call` you can use Array methods on nodeList.

Try the below code:

```
function ccbfunction(wt) {
    var w = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    var z;
    if (wt == 0) {
        z = "#e0e0e0";
    } else {
        z = "#fff";
    };
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(w, function(node, index) {
        node.style.filter = "brightness(80%)";
    })
    w[0].style.filter = "brightness(80%)";
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You use the below logic.

```
   $('img').each(function(){
      //Write your logic here
    });
```

Comment: According to OP, using `jQuery` isn't a choice!